# Broken permalinks in Wordpress on Fedora

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I've been bashing my head for the last couple of days and can't figure it out :( No other option for permalinks doesn't work except Simple.

Fedora 23, Wordpress 4.9.8,  Apache/2.4.23 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.0.2j-fips PHP/7.0.22

httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Changing CHMOD to 660, 666, 777 didn't work.

Tried that trick where you just "refresh" permalinks by clicking Save settings button. Doesn't work either.

Mod_rewrite is enabled as well.

**EDIT**

```
<?php

/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('WP_CACHE', true);
define( 'WPCACHEHOME', '/var/www/html/wpsite/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/' );
define('DB_NAME', 'wpsite');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', ' :D ');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         ' :D ');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  ' :D ');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    ' :D ');
define('NONCE_KEY',        ' :D ');
define('AUTH_SALT',        ' :D ');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', ' :D ');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   ' :D ');
define('NONCE_SALT',       ' :D ');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wpsite_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the Codex.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Everything looks normal in wp-config.php

Comment: can you post part of your `wp-config.php` file maybe some setting in there?

Comment: Added in the original post.

Comment: i suspect that supercache might interfere with permalinks working, try disabling cache/supercache and see what gives

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by a plugin. 
Connect through FTP and rename the plugins folder in the wp-content to something else and try to refresh your page. if it worked then just rename the plugins folder once again to its original name "plugins". this will disable all plugins on your website. then you can test which one is causing the problem. i hope it helps. 
Good luck

Answer (score -1):

The same problem still exists in Fedora 29, Wordpress 4.9.8, Apache 2.4.37-3, php 7.2.12-1 (all installed using the Fedora packages).

One thing that might help people diagnose the problem: RedHat supplies Wordpress in a pretty locked-down mode that prevents the installation of plugins:

define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true);

in wp-config.php prevents wordpress from even displaying the "add plugin" button.  Is it possible that something similar is preventing the permalinks from working?

There are no plugins installed, and opcache is not installed.